# Glob different file extension in bash script for loop

Tags: bash, glob

I can't spot the error here, why is it not globbing but using `ls *.{jpg,JPEG,JPG,jpeg,PNG,png}` it runs perfectly?

How to fix it?

```
for file in *.{jpg,JPEG,JPG,jpeg,PNG,png}
  do
echo $file
  #convert "${file}" -scale 50% gallery_"${file}".jpg
done
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you use the direct glob? The only problem I see is that it'll leave unexpanded globs for any extensions that don't have matches (e.g. if there are no ".JPEG" files, you'll get `*.JPEG` as one of the results). The `ls` version, on the other hand, doesn't work: it runs the loop just once, with all filenames in `$file` with newlines between them.

Comment: Which you can handle with `[ -s "$file" ] && convert "$file" ...` simply testing the file exists and has a non-zero size.  ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason it is the No. 1 pitfall...)

Comment: Yes the `ls` was definitely a bad idea. I'm getting rid of that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `nullglob` to avoid unexpanded globs:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```